# How do you execute a method in a class from the command line

Tags: php, command-line

Basically I have a PHP class that that I want to test from the commandline and run a certain method. I am sure this is a basic question, but I am missing something from the docs. I know how to run a file, obviously `php -f` but not sure how to run that file which is a class and execute a given method

Comment: ok thanks, this might of been a dumb question :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This will work:

```
php -r 'include "MyClass.php"; MyClass::foo();'
```

But I don't see any reasons do to that besides testing though.

Comment: That's the most awesome trick I found for command line since I started looking for it :)

Comment: I found I can't use this method of I'm making use of the $this keyword for variables I've defined as attributes. (e.g. `public function __construct(){ $this->foo = bar;} public function stuff(){ echo $this->foo;}`) If I try to call the class method `MyClass::stuff()`, then I would get an error.

Comment: @VinceOmega - because you're statically calling the method (bypassing the constructor) and cannot access non-static properties.

Answer (score 14):

I would probably use call_user_func to avoid harcoding class or method names.
Input should probably use some kinf of validation, though...

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function Sum($a, $b)
    {
        $sum = $a+$b;
        echo "Sum($a, $b) = $sum";
    }
}


// position [0] is the script's file name
array_shift(&$argv);
$className = array_shift(&$argv);
$funcName = array_shift(&$argv);

echo "Calling '$className::$funcName'...\n";

call_user_func_array(array($className, $funcName), $argv);

?>
```

Result:

```
E:\>php testClass.php MyClass Sum 2 3
Calling 'MyClass::Sum'...
Sum(2, 3) = 5
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a neater example of Repox's code. This will only run de method when called from the commandline.

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
  public function hello()
  {
    return "world";
  }
}

// Only run this when executed on the commandline
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
    $obj = new MyClass();
    echo $obj->hello();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

As Pekka already mentioned, you need to write a script that handles the execution of the specific method and then run it from your commandline.

test.php:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
  public function hello()
  {
    return "world";
  }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->hello();
?>
```

And in your commandline

```
php -f test.php
```