# PHP Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed line 14

Tags: php

I got this error

PHP Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed on line 14

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public function Sum($a, $b)
    {
        $sum = $a+$b;
        echo "Sum($a, $b) = $sum";
    }
}


// position [0] is the script's file name
array_shift(&$argv);
$className = array_shift(&$argv);
$funcName = array_shift(&$argv);

echo "Calling '$className::$funcName'...\n";

call_user_func_array(array($className, $funcName), $argv);

?>
```

and here is what I use in my command line

```
E:\>php testClass.php MyClass Sum 2 3
```

as I following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969735/how-do-you-execute-a-method-in-a-class-from-the-command-line)

What have I done wrong here ? I am new to PHP but trying to slowly learn. Please suggest. Thanks,

Comment: Change to `array_shift($argv);` http://php.net/manual/language.references.pass.php

Comment: The ampersand belongs in the function argument list, not in the call argument list. That has been changed years ago, I think when php4 came out...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need &$argv but $argv in all of your line.