# How to execute a PHP script who depends on project classes?

Tags: php, class, execute

I have to execute a script which is in the project's root directory.

My script is instancing some classes, but unfortunately, it says that my class isn't found when I do a "PHP myscript.php".

I can try with includes, but I have several errors when a class extends another (external abstract class). Is there a way to make this script "part of the project", in order to not include each class?

I read a similar question but it does not answer exactly to my question: [How do you execute a method in a class from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969735/how-do-you-execute-a-method-in-a-class-from-the-command-line)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want a script that is reusable I would recommend creating a command and executing that command when needed.

See: [The laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#generating-commands)

**EDIT**

Sorry, I falsely pressumend you were using the Laravel Framework, for Zend see: [The Zend/console docs](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html)

Comment: This is what I was just looking for, but for Zend Framework it doesn't seems native like laravel or symfony